# Spring boot - multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate existing spring web application (**Spring version 4.1.X**) to Spring boot (**version 1.3**),

I am using web.xml in the application, There I have configured listener.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.package.config.WebApplicationContextConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.package.application.ApplicationContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.servlet.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>contextClass</description>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.package.config.SpringWebMvcConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In the listener I am calling super contextIntialized.

```
public class ApplicationContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    super.contextInitialized(event);
```

Application is failing at below location which is available in ContextLoader.class

```
public WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    if (servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE) != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - " +
                "check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!");
    }
```

**I am getting below error.**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:297) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at com.package.application.ApplicationContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationContextLoaderListener.java:47) ~[classes/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31][enter image description here][1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Jars used in the application are placed below.
[image]

Comment: If you want to migrate to Spring Boot, first step is get rid of web.xml file, avoid xml configuration and use only annotations

Comment: @cralfaro Thank you for response. I have migrated web.xml to java config file now, Even-though I am getting same error.

Comment: What is so special about your `ApplicationContextLoaderListener` that you even need it? Also Spring Boot already loads the root context so you shouldn't register your own listener.

Comment: @M.Deinum We are using **ApplicationContextLoaderListener** to get DB state and cache data from DB. So, we need this application specific listener. Can you please suggest how we need inform spring boot to use user defined listener.

Comment: Why would you need an `ApplicationContextLoaderListener` for that? You are probably better of writing an `ApplicationLIstener` that listens for events that does that instead of a customized context loader.

Comment: I need to use **ApplicationContextLoaderListener** in the application, Is there any way in spring boot takes user defined listener instead of root context.
Tried using **ApplicationLIstener** instead of user defined listener getting new error.
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type specified [com.package.application.ApplicationListener] is not one of the expected listener types**

Comment: In **ApplicationContextLoaderListener** we are getting  **WebApplicationContext** and it is having some data which we are using in the ApplicationContextLoaderListener, but it is coming as null in current boot implementation **ApplicationContextLoaderListener** class.

Comment: I have same issue, any solution found now ? please post it here as answer

Answer (score 0):

Even though some time has passed - for anyone experiencing the same error:

There are two context loaders - one will (usually) be in the web.xml:

**I)**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.package.application.ApplicationContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And for the 2nd one there are two possible places:

**IIa)**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ...
```

=> When you check the code of the `SpringBootServletInitializer.java` class you'll find the following line in the `onStartup(...)` method:

```
public void onStartup(...){
   servletContext.addListener(new SpringBootContextLoaderListener(rootApplicationContext, servletContext));
```

=> I just removed the `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` part and it was working.

**OR**

**IIb)**

If you use an `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` - in the startup also the `addListener()` method is called.

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer{
   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException{
     ...
     super.onStartup(servletContext);
   }
}
```